# mysql database normalisation

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, database-normalization

I'm new to mysql! have absolutely basic knowledge like creating tables only.
I'm in the process of creating a website with online examinations and results. My fields include

```
t_id, t_name(subject),ru_id, ru_name, ru_skl, hs_user, hsu_skl
```

*Legend*: t is test. ru is registered users. skl is school. hs is high scored. hsu is high scored user.

I don't know how to **arrange the fields in tables and to establish a relationship** such that the following conditions are met:
(1) each test can have multiple users registering, for the same test_id.
(2) highest scored user should be obtained and entered into table, for the respective test_id.
(3) highest scored user's school should also be entered into table, for the respective test_id.
(4) conditions 2 n 3 should be retrievable so as to process using php for monthly toppers list, etc.

Kindly require ur help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table: UserToTest
Columns:

```
test_id | user_id | score
```

That is actually all you need. Just insert `user_id` and `test_id` to establish the relationship. Add the `score` as additional information.

All the other data you want to have, max score by user and max score by school are values you can easily compute when querying. So there is no real need to write it in a table, it would only make the datahandling more complicated as you would have to add triggers, constraints or more logic in your application to keep those values up to date.

Comment: Tq for ur ans!! i get wt u mean, bt wt if i have to add points for the user who scored max, and then to the school, such as to create sumtn like a leaderboards, etc., which have to be updated at specific time intervals. Then, wouldn't i need to store the values of scores, etc, as i would be displaying it in a webpage...?

Comment: No, you don't have to store them. Also when you are computing them as you are querying there will be no problem like "updated at specific intervals" as the computed values will always be up to date. But if you really really want to save those values, you should put them into the test-table, as it has nothing to do with the actual relations but is a specific statistic for a test.

Comment: will definitely try ur valuable suggestion...Tnx a lot!!

Comment: Nice :) Feel free to ask when you need help with those queries for the leaderboard, sometimes they aren't as easy as one first might think. Also please accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: y tnq, again!! If ur fairly proficient with php pdo, kindly send me ur email ID...Dat'd b easier i suppose!